# WP Mail SMTP Version 1.5.1 not sending test Mails

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, wordpress-theming, phpmailer

I have configured the WP Mail SMTP plugin in my wordpress site but after configuration I'm testing the plugin working or not, While testing it giving bel;low Error:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'reconfigure_smtp' );
function reconfigure_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
    $SMTPhost = get_option('smtp_host');
    $SMTPport = get_option('smtp_port');
    $FromEmail = get_option('mail_from');
    $FromName = get_option('mail_from_name');
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host =$SMTPhost;
    $phpmailer->Port = $SMTPport;
    $phpmailer->From = $FromEmail;
    $phpmailer->FromName = $FromName;
}
```

Click here to view the full Error Log for debugging:

```
WordPress: 5.1.1
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.0.33-5+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
WP Mail SMTP: 1.4.2

Params:
Mailer: smtp
Constants: No
ErrorInfo: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
SMTPSecure: ssl
SMTPAutoTLS: bool(true)
SMTPAuth: bool(true)

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019
Apache.mod_security: No
SMTP Debug:
2019-07-16 09:54:17 Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array (
)
2019-07-16 09:54:17 Connection: opened
2019-07-16 09:54:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP g35sm11776763qtg.92 - gsmtp
2019-07-16 09:54:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.ZZZZZ.com
2019-07-16 09:54:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [34.200.115.143]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
2019-07-16 09:54:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2019-07-16 09:54:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2019-07-16 09:54:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y29udGFjdGFoZXhAZ21haWwuY29t
2019-07-16 09:54:17 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2019-07-16 09:54:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: YTFoMmUzeDRAIyQ=
2019-07-16 09:54:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please
534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g35sm11776763qtg.92 - gsmtp
2019-07-16 09:54:18 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please
534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g35sm11776763qtg.92 - gsmtp
2019-07-16 09:54:18 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2019-07-16 09:54:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-07-16 09:54:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection g35sm11776763qtg.92 - gsmtp
2019-07-16 09:54:18 Connection: closed
2019-07-16 09:54:18 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

There was a problem while sending the test email.

Could not connect to the SMTP host.

This means your web server was unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com.

Typically this error is returned for one of the following reasons:

-SMTP settings are incorrect (wrong port, security setting, incorrect host).
-Your web server is blocking the connection.
-Your SMTP host is rejecting the connection.

Recommended next steps:
Triple check your SMTP settings including host address, email, and password, port, and security.
Contact your web hosting provider and ask them to verify your server can connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 using tls encryption. Additionally, ask them if a firewall or security policy may be preventing the connection - many shared hosts block certain ports.
Note: this is the most common cause of this issue.
Contact your SMTP host to confirm you are using the correct username and password.
Verify with your SMTP host that your account has permissions to send emails using outside connections.

Comment: 'Your SMTP host is rejecting the connection' this clearly stated that the connection is rejected by the Gmail SMTP server. You need to check the configuration you are setting.

Comment: Thank's for responce, How can I check  the configuration ?

Comment: Have you purchased the G Suite? You can configure the Gmail SMTP only if you have purchased the license

Comment: BTW, because you are using an old version of PHPMailer, your debug log includes your ID and password in an easily-decoded format, so I suggest you **change your password**. I have edited out the offending data, but it was exposed, and that's bad enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First need to check SMTP Details like (SMTP Host,Encryption,SMTP Username adn SMTP Password) after that need to enable the less secure app in our gmail or yahoo settings.